# Change font size only in a part of a document

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I have created my thesis using `mathptmx` size `12pt`. I would use in only a part Latin Modern but not `12pt` instead `11pt`. How can I achieve that? I tought to `\small` but I don't know if correspond to the correct size

Comment: for the basic latex document classes, in fact `\small` is `11pt` when option `12pt` is used.  this is set in the file `size12.clo` (or a comparable one for the `book` class) with the code `\newcommand\small{\@setfontsize\small\@xipt{13.6}...`, where `\@xipt` designates `11pt` using the roman numeral to construct a valid alphabetic command name.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, is 13.6 the value for `\baselineskip` here?

Comment: 13.6 is the value set for 11pt text in both `size12.clo` and `bk12.clo`.  (you didn't say what document class you're using.)  the ams document classes use 13 for `\small` in a `12pt` document.  so different publishers have different opinions on the subject.  check your document `.cls` file (if it has the values built in) or your `.log` file to see what `.clo` files are read in and check there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the font size in document is set as `12pt`, the definitions are used from the file `size12.clo` (you can see it in the log file). `size12.clo` defines `\small` as

```
\newcommand\small{%
   \@setfontsize\small\@xipt{13.6}%
   \abovedisplayskip 11\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus6\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 6.5\p@ \@plus3.5\p@ \@minus3\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \topsep 9\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus5\p@
               \parsep 4.5\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
               \itemsep \parsep}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
```

Hence `\small` is using `11pt` size. Hence you can use `\small`.

The other method is to use `\fontsize{<font size>}{interline skip>}\selectfont` where the interline skip is usually 120% of font size.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{.47\textwidth}}}\hline
{   %% Open a group to make the effect of \small local
\small
\lipsum[1]
}   %% Close the group
&
{
\fontsize{11}{13.6}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]
}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work. The fontsize doesn't return to what it was after the closing brace.

Answer (score 5):

```
foo{\fontsize{11pt}{13.2pt}\selectfont foo}foo
```

The first number is for the font size and the second one is for `\baselineskip`, usually 1.2 times the font size.

[image]

Comment: a changed `\baselineskip` won't take effect unless it's the value in effect when a paragraph break occurs.  so although it's always a good idea to use an appropriate value, in the case shown here, it could even be `0pt` or `30pt` with no effect.

Comment: About the fontsize, are non-integer values allowed? It seems that putting 11 or 11.3 has no effect. There is a threshold say 11.5 where it seems to round to a bigger number.

Comment: Same answer, still doesn't work. The font size stays changed after the closing brace if there are many lines and pagebreaks inside the braces.