# Change font size mid document consistently

Tags: fontsize

How can I cange the fontsize mid document to have the same effect locally as setting the fontsize in the documentclass globally.

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section*{Text in 12pt}

Some text

\footnotesize footnotesize 
\small small 
\normalsize normalsize
\large large



\newlength{\FSize}
\setlength{\FSize}{10pt}
\newlength{\Baselineskip}
\setlength{\Baselineskip}{1.2\FSize} % Compare http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94385/4011

\section*{Text in  10pt}

\fontsize{\FSize}{\Baselineskip}\selectfont

Some text

\footnotesize footnotesize 
\small small 
\normalsize normalsize
\large large


\end{document}
```

This gives the following output

[image: output]

As you can see, this is not what I wanted, setting the font size this way locally it doesn't have locally the same effect as correspeondingly setting the fontsize in the option of the documentclass globally. For example commands like `\section` or `\small` are not changed (but if I change the font in the documentclass they **do** change).

So is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no standard way to do this (and it's not clear you should do:-) the standard classes only define one set of section headings, list spacing and document text size once, depending on the global class option (that's why it is a global option) the values for other sizes are not loaded at all so not directly available.

Comment: Couldn't the `relsize` package (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/relsize) be a first approach?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207814/change-base-fontsize-for-rest-of-document

Comment: And there is no standard set of definitions corresponding to 8pt. [If you specified 8pt as a class option, you'd just get 10pt.]

Comment: @cfr I just canged the example!

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is setup by `sizeXX.clo`.  There most of the font size changing commands are set by `\newcommand` so you need to undefine them before loading this file.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section*{Text in 12pt}

Some text

\footnotesize footnotesize 
\small small 
\normalsize normalsize
\large large

\makeatletter
\let\small\@undefined
\let\footnotesize\@undefined
\let\scriptsize\@undefined
\let\tiny\@undefined
\let\large\@undefined
\let\Large\@undefined
\let\LARGE\@undefined
\let\huge\@undefined
\let\Huge\@undefined
\input{size10.clo}\makeatother
\section*{Text in  10pt}

Some text

\footnotesize footnotesize 
\small small 
\normalsize normalsize
\large large


\end{document}
```

Probably you want to do a `\clearpage` before the switch.

Comment: See Also: [This Answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/switching-to-different-font-sizes-locally/15838#15838) which does the same thing, but fiddles with `\newcommand` rather than undefine all the sizing commands.

Comment: @DeanSerenevy Thanks for that clean solution.  It looks like this question should be closed as a duplicate.